# How to use Unicode literals with the Node.js -e "evaluate script" commandline switch

Tags: node.js, windows, unicode, escaping, unicode-literals

Node.js has an `-e` commandline switch to evaluate code provided on the commandline rather than in a separate script file.

Oddly, I can't find official documentation for it online but the node executable self-documents it if you run `node --help`:

```
>node --help
Usage: node [options] [ -e script | script.js ] [arguments]
       node debug script.js [arguments]

Options:
  -v, --version         print Node.js version
  -e, --eval script     evaluate script
  -p, --print           evaluate script and print result
```

Now there are several ways to use Unicode literals in JavaScript, all seemingly begin with `\u`.

But no matter how I try to quote or escape the string with the Unicode literal, the code always fails to execute. Both under official Node.js and also JXcore.

**Node**

```
>node -e console.log('hello \u00A9')
[eval]:1
console.log('hello
            ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at node.js:578:27
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

**JXcore**

```
>jx -e console.log('hello \u{00A9}')
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal ([eval] 1:12)
    at  ([eval]-wrapper:6:8)
    at Module.prototype._compile (module.js:621:10)
    at evalScript (node.js:1054:18)
    at startup (node.js:419:7)
    at node.js:1604:3
```

I've tried double `\\` and quadruple `\\\\`. I've tried single and double quote characters to delimit the strings.

(I am only trying this under Windows, just in case this might work fine under *nix.)

Comment: Are you trying to execute this from `cmd.exe`? Or PowerShell?

Comment: From `cmd.exe`. I never learned to like PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
node -e "console.log('hello \u00A9')"
```

Double-quoting ensures that `console.log('hello \u00A9')` is interpreted as a *single* argument by `node`.

In your original attempt, `node` saw *2* arguments following `-e` (split by the space inside `'hello \u00A9'`): `console.log('hello` and `\u00A9')`, and since the first argument following `-e` was not by itself a syntactically valid expression, you got a syntax error.

---

**Background:**

The `script`argument (`-e`'s option-argument) containing the snippet of JavaScript code to execute must be a *distinct* argument on the command line, so that it can be distinguished from other arguments, such as the arguments to pass to it (`[arguments]`).

The way to make a string with embedded whitespace distinct as an argument is to *quote it as a whole*.

On Windows, this is typically done with *double* quotes, but it is ultimately up to the program invoked to interpret the arguments (after the shell may have expanded tokens, such as environment-variable references).

Since single- and double-quoting can be used interchangeably in JavaScript, you *may* even get away with swapping single- and double quotes: `node -e 'console.log("hello \u00A9")'`

(That definitely works on Unix, where *the shell itself* recognizes a single-quoted string as a distinct argument, and all programs are handed an array of parsed arguments rather than a command line to interpret themselves).

Comment: Wow I really was sure I had tried every combination and permutation of quotes. But getting a deterministic answer with explanation is better than undeterministically trying permutations (-: This does indeed work with Nodejs, JXcore, and MS's ChakraCore port of Node too!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I've added some more background info.