# Unable to get the NodeJS epoch time from a Python script

Tags: python, node.js, subprocess

I'm sorry if this question is a dupe, but I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171791/how-to-suppress-or-capture-the-output-of-subprocess-run) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159591/capture-output-from-node-command-in-python), yet was still unable to find a solution.

I just want to execute the following bash command in my Python script to get the current epoch timestamp integer via NodeJS:

```bash
node -e "console.log(Date.now());"
```

The output is as expected, but when I run this in Python:

```py
nodejs_list = ["node", "-e", '"console.log(Date.now());"']
node_time = subprocess.run(
    nodejs_list,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
print(node_time)
```

All I'm able to get is the `CompletedProcess()` output, but not the time integer:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['node', '-e', '"console.log(Date.now());"'], returncode=0, stdout='', stderr='')
```

I've even tried:

```py
subprocess.run(nodejs_list, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip("\n")
```

And:

```py
subprocess.check_output(nodejs_list)
```

But these don't return what I need either.

I'm assuming it's because Python is unable to capture the output of Node's `console.log()` or something. Is there someway to "flush" the NodeJS output? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this `node -e "console.log(Date.now());"` in terminal, it is working. Bash shell will accept this without any problem. `NodeJs` will execute `console.log(Date.now());`, and this will produce an output to `stdout`

But you use extra `quotes` in `subprocess.run` func, and this causing `'"console.log(Date.now());"'` interpreted as a string like "console.log(Date.now());" in `NodeJs`.  That's why, `NodeJs` does not produce any output. To solve this, we can do like below ;

```
nodejs_list = ["node", "-e", "console.log(Date.now());"]
node_time = subprocess.run(
    nodejs_list,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
print(node_time.stdout.strip())
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292600/how-to-use-unicode-literals-with-the-node-js-e-evaluate-script-commandline-sw)

Comment: Yes! That was the trick. Thank you.